# how to add online payment option(ccavenu) to the mvc application in .net

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ccavenue

How to integrate ccavenue online payment option in to mvc application. Is there any reference links to go through for ccavenue integration in my web application?

i tried searching in google but i didnt found any solutions regarding online payment in .net.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have just found out some reference for you.

You can Login into your CCAvenue account and download the Integration Kit (DLL) as per your requirement in Resources -> Web Integration Kit ->  as shown in the below screenshot:

[image: ref]

source: http://aravin.net/how-to-integration-ccavenue-payment-gateway-into-your-website-using-asp-net-with-screenshot/